# How to change the Radiobutton display text

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, radio-button

I did try to go through the solutions suggested by stackoverflow. But didnt find an answer i am trying to solve  .

---

[image: Replace the Button Text]
I have a radio button as given above.   My idea is to change the  text in the radio button group based on the value in  text box 
 So logically  when i enter  3, i need the reference  text to be changed to   " Primary  file is 3" .

---

I have following code to change the text . This is also getting fired from when the text box entry changes

> rbtCurrentFile_CheckedChanged(sender,e);

```
protected void rbtCurrentFile_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            rbtCurrentFile.Text="Primary File is  "+Request["referenceNumber"];

            rtbnRefernceFile.Text="Primary File is  "+txtProspectorNumber.Text;
        }
```

The text is not changing .   Here is the aspx code  too

---

`<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtCurrentFile" runat="server" GroupName="primaryFile" Text="Primary File" OnCheckedChanged="rbtCurrentFile_CheckedChanged" />
                <br />
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rtbnRefernceFile" runat="server" GroupName="primaryFile" Text="Reference File" />
                <br />`

Comment: Is that `WebForms`?

Comment: yes it is  web form

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the properties `Text="Primary File"` and `Text="Reference File"` in aspx
2. Initialize `rbtCurrentFile.Text="Primary File"` and `rtbnRefernceFile.Text="Reference File"` in the `Page_Load` event (place this initialization inside `if Page.IsPostBack{}`)
3. Leave `rbtCurrentFile_CheckedChanged` as is

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Firing from   textbox entry is not working